# iOS How Instagram changes without updates

Tags: ios, instagram

Sometimes, I open the Instagram app and notice that a new feature has been added, such as a custom header or new buttons. It's been a whole year since I last updated the app, and I've also disabled the auto-update for the App Store.

I'm curious about how Instagram implements these changes. I would be grateful if you could recommend some technology for that. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Features of a mobile app can be toggled by feature flags controlled by backend. It is likely that the features are already implemented in the app, but they are hidden until Meta decides that it is ready to be available to you. (as experiments or full release of the features)